# How to implement a configurable spring force to SpringJoint2D like SpringJoint does?

Tags: physics, unity

I'm working in unity 5.3.4f1.

Looking at the [SpringJoint2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpringJoint2D.html) class I can't seem to find a similar "spring force" as in [spring](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpringJoint-spring.html) in SpringJoint.

Is there any other way to make a spring stronger in SpringJoint2D?

If not, the only option I see is to inherit the [Joint2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint2D.html) parent class and build my own spring joint 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good way around. You can use [DistanceJoint2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DistanceJoint2D.html), get the reaction force and build your own spring model by doing F/K = x where x is the distance travelled away from the natural distance and K is your spring constant.